# How to Import a Scenario into Warlords II Deluxe?

Tags: warlords-ii-deluxe

Warlords II Deluxe is an old Windows game that I run inside DosBox on my Windows 7.  I have acquired a bunch of custom scenarios that come as .scz files and want to use them in Warlords.

But for the life of me I can't figure out how to import them.  How can I do it?

There is supposed to be a "librarian" that will import them, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, it figures.  As soon as I post a question I figure it out.  I managed to scrounge up an old manual for Warlords II Deluxe.

If you run the program `install.exe`, you can access the *librarian* which will unpack saved scenarios into the scenario directory so you can play them.

Comment: We still appreciate you posting the question (and the answer you found!) for the benefit of anyone else who might be trying to play Warlords II in this day and age!